# How to fetch aerospike data with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, aerospike

Is there any way to fetch aerospike data with jmeter. 
i need to pass the key value from jmeter for which data value should be fetched from aerospike.

Answer (score 3):

Given you have [JDBC Driver for Aerospike NOSQL Database](https://github.com/anandintouch/aerospike-jdbc-connector) in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you can use [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) to set up database URL and credentials and [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler to run your queries and store results into [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) for detailed instructions on setting up JMeter for database testing.